# If $f_n\to f$ a.e. and are bounded in $L^p$ norm, then $\int f_n g\to \int fg$ for any $g\in L^q$

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, convergence-divergence, lp-spaces

Suppose $p>1$ and $q$ is its conjugate exponent. Suppose $f_n \rightarrow f~a.e.$ and $\sup_n\|f_n\|_p < \infty $. prove that if $g \in L^q,$ then $\lim_{n \rightarrow \infty} \int f_ng=\int fg.$ Does this extend to the case where $p=1$ and $q=\infty$? If not, give a counter example.

#### Progress

I know I need to prove $|\int (f_ng-fg)| < \epsilon$ and $|\int (f_ng-fg)| < |\int (f_n-f)g|$, if $f_n \rightarrow f$ in $ L^p $. I can use Holder's inequality to get the result. My question is how to get $f_n \rightarrow f $ in $L^p $ by the hypothesis $f_n \rightarrow f~a.e.$ and $\sup_n\|f_n\|_p < \infty$ or use other method to get the result. thanks

Comment: Have you considered the dominated convergence theorem?

Comment: @Prahlad Vaidyanathan how? $sup_n||f_n||_p< \infty$ tells us $f_n \in L^p$, then get the dominated function $f_N$? even I find the dominated function g, then use the dominated convergence theorem in $L^p$ to get $f_n \rightarrow f $in $L^p$?

Comment: What can you say about $h := \sup |f_n|$?

Comment: @PrahladVaidyanathan: $h$ may not be in $L^p$.

Comment: Is the measure of the underlying space finite? Any conditions on the underlying space?

Comment: @copper.hat there is no condition for space

Comment: I found answer in this website：http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/910117/show-that-for-any-g-in-l-pe-where-p-is-the-conjugate-of-p-lim/910209#910209

Comment: These answers are incomplete, but this question has been answered fully at http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/442550/pointwise-convergence-and-boundedness-in-norm-imply-weak-convergence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have $\int |f|^p = \int \liminf_n |f_n|^p \le \liminf_n \int |f_n|^p < \infty$, so $f \in L^p$.

Counterexample for $p=1$:
Let $X=[0,1]$, $f_n=n1_{[0,{1 \over n}]}$, $\|f_n\|_1 = 1$, $f_n(x) \to 0$ ae.,
and let $g=1$. Then
$\int f_n g = 1$ for all $n$, but $\int 0 g = 0$.

Comment: how to show $\int |f|^p = \int \liminf_n |f_n|^p$

Comment: You are given $f_n(x) \to f(x)$ ae., so $|f_n(x)| \to |f(x)|$ ae., so $\liminf_n |f_n(x)|^p = \lim_n |f_n(x)|^p = |f(x)|^p$ ae.

Comment: We are using Fatou's lemma here.

Comment: Yes,the second equality is by Fatou lemma. After we know $f \in L^p$, then how to continue it?

Comment: @aliyun: You don't need to accept the answer, I haven't answered all of it. I think one could use Egorov's theorem to answer this, but this requires the underlying space to have finite measure.

Answer (score 0):

For $p> 1$ it is true that $\int{f_ng}\rightarrow\int{fg}$. This follows from [Theorem 3](http://www.jstor.org/stable/2319009?seq=3#page_scan_tab_contents). Because the cited theorem has a different notation, I will write the body of it with your notation (in terms of $p$, $L_p$ ) and then apply it.

**Theorem 3.**

*Let $M$ be a positive constant and $(X,\mu)$ be a complete measure space. Suppose that $0<p\leq \infty$ and that $f,\,f_1,\,f_2,....$ is a sequence of $\mu-$measurable functions, such that 
$\|f_n\|_p\leq M,\,\,n=1,2,...$ 
and 
$\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{f_n(x)}=f(x)\quad$  $\mu-$a.e $x\in X$.
 Then $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\|f_ng-fg\|_s}=0$ for every $s\in(0,p)$ and every $g\in L_q(X)$, where $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{s}{p}=1$*

Now you apply this theorem with $p>1$, $s=1\in(0,p)$ and $\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{p}=1$. You get that $\lim\limits_{n\rightarrow\infty}{\|f_ng-fg\|_1}=0\Leftrightarrow \int\limits_{X}{|f_ng-fg|d\mu}=0$. Consequently $|\int\limits_{X}{(f_ng-fg)d\mu}|\leq \int\limits_{X}{|f_ng-fg|d\mu}\rightarrow 0$